# Database Recovery Model Update

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking for some advice.  Yesterday my production database was updated from Recovery Model = full to Recovery Model = simple by "someone".  Tracking it through it appears it may have been the SQLService account but I can't be 100% sure on that.  The knock on effect of the change affected my transaction log restores for my reporting/cube databases.

I've only ever seen/done the recovery mode change via the Options or SQL script.

Has anyone ever seen the recovery mode get changed by a service account or any other means other than manually doing it?

I really want to find out how this occurred and if you have any tips/advice on tracking through who could have done it would be even better.  The logs gave me a SPID for the change which linked back to the SQLService account but that's as far as I've managed to get.

thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like it's something that happened through the SQL Agent Services most likely a a scheduled tast. Most likely setup by someone who wanted to minimize logging on a heavy data load or index maintance... Rather than putting the database in BULK LOGGED they put it into SIMPLE and destroyed the log chain. My advise, if you're able, look at the tasks that immediatly followed the swith. Hopefully, that will give you some idea which job has the offending code.

Comment: Check error log? Change of recovery model is normally logged in the SQL Server errorlog..